# Is it OK to use Keycloak as user database?

Tags: architecture, microservices, keycloak

We are building an application using microservice approach and we'd like to use Keycloak as our authentication / authorization service. Our application will require a lot of personal data from the user (addresses, telephones, different personal certificates, insurances etc.) and we need to store that - can/should we extend Keycloak to be able to store all of these user data? What are the advantages / disadvantages of such approach?

If we keep all data in Keycloak, is it ok if some of our microservices will query Keycloak to get other users data? (e.g. Role "agent" user wants to checkout 10 most recent users and their submitted data) - or should we store just minimal data in Keycloak and design a separated service for all user data?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Vault](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault).

Answer (score 9):

***I would not*** use keycloak as database to store users' info.

Keycloak provides interfaces (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_user-storage-spi), you can easily make custom **User storage SPI**, which can connect to your application's database

Advantages are:

- You can use mappers to map users attributes into users' tokens
- You do not need to touch keycloak database (it should be used only by keycloak)
- Scalability (for each realm, you can have different **user storage SPI**)